# Implement Google Analytic on Website Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-analytics-api

I am looking to integrate Google Analytic in django website in html page or in django admin. I need to show the show data in Graphical format on Separate HTML Page. The Graphical data will be based on number of visitor on page in a month. My Website is purely based on Python Django.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: https://pypi.org/project/django-google-analytics-app/

It supports the latest version of python.